# HTML5 and JS front end with c# backend

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is it possible to have a dynamic website built using HTML5, CSS, JS and have it link to a backend using c#?

Am new to the whole microsoft side of development (coming from a php background) and haven't a clue.

thinking in terms of medium to enterprise applications.

thanks

Comment: Yes.  It's called ASP.NET.

Comment: Take a look at SignalIR https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR its more of a pure C# approach to writing a web app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use asp.net mvc...This is what you want: http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4

Here is a bunch of good video tutorials:  http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/pluralsight-building-applications-with-aspnet-mvc-4

Comment: +1. The Pluralsight MVC4 video is awesome. totally recommended.

Comment: Thanks - it's kind of overwhelming at first glance!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Although I'd recommend looking at things like Angular.js (its what Gmail uses) to provide the best experience on the front-end. The backend can still be C# either ASP.NET[MVC] or WebAPI.

Comment: Too many frameworks duplicating each other. I would like to abstragate from them all.